# I have a problem about \twocolumn

Tags: two-column

Please look the picture 1 ,I don't use the \twocolumn,the title is correct [image: picture 1]

when i use the \twocolumn[mytitile],i want the following text be divided into two columns.
But the title become the picture 2  not the picture 1 [image: picture 2]
the skip of title and head rule is wrong.
how to solve the problem or this may be not a problem ?

This is my code.

```
`\documentclass{ctexart}
 \newcommand{\mtitle}[1]
 {\begin{center}\bfseries\bigskip\zihao{-2}#1\end{center}}
 \newcommand{\mauthorinfo}[2]{\begin{center}\fangsong{\zihao{4}#1} \\ 
 \songti{#2}\end{center}}
 \usepackage{lastpage}%获得总页数

 \usepackage
  [left=1.95cm,right=1.95cm,top=2.15cm,bottom=2.15cm,
   headsep=0.45cm,footskip=0.88cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}

  \lhead{}
  \chead{\zihao{-5}\kaishu 示例示例示例示例}
  \rhead{}
  \lfoot{}
  \cfoot{\thepage}
  \rfoot{}%当前页 of 总页数
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%改为0pt即可去掉页眉下面的横线
   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%改为0pt即可去掉页脚上面的横线
   \setlength{\headheight}{12.7pt}
   \begin{document}
   \thispagestyle{fancy}
   \twocolumn[
   \mtitle{示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例}
    \mauthorinfo{示例示例}{示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例}
   ]
 \section{模型}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your problem comes from the use of \bigskip in \mtitle. At the top pf the page it is ignored, but not inside the \twocolumn box.  The center environment also adds an extra line above and below.

Comment: THAKS, YOU ARE SO SMART。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can duplicate the effects of a new page (ignoring extra space at the top and bottom) using a minipage.  However, both the page and the minipage start with \vskip\topskip, which is one too many.  Also, the bottom of the minipage absorbs the extra space at the bottom of `\mauthorinfo`, hense the `\hrule`.

i can't figure out why the section title is being centered.

```
 \documentclass{ctexart}
 \newcommand{\mtitle}[1]
  {\begin{center}\bfseries\bigskip\zihao{-2}#1\end{center}}
 \newcommand{\mauthorinfo}[2]{\begin{center}\fangsong{\zihao{4}#1} \\ 
 \songti{#2}\end{center}}
 \usepackage{lastpage}%获得总页数

 \usepackage
  [left=1.95cm,right=1.95cm,top=2.15cm,bottom=2.15cm,
   headsep=0.45cm,footskip=0.88cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}

  \lhead{}
  \chead{\zihao{-5}\kaishu 示例示例示例示例}
  \rhead{}
  \lfoot{}
  \cfoot{\thepage}
  \rfoot{}%当前页 of 总页数
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%改为0pt即可去掉页眉下面的横线
   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%改为0pt即可去掉页脚上面的横线
   \setlength{\headheight}{12.7pt}
   \begin{document}
   \thispagestyle{fancy}
   \twocolumn[\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\vskip-\topskip% duplicate
    \mtitle{示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例}
       \mauthorinfo{示例示例}{示例示例示例示例示例示例示例示例}
   \hrule height0pt\end{minipage}]
 \section{模型}
 \end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: THANK YOU ! I know this solution, the problem(maybe not) is the skip  between the title and the top of the page is not what i want

Comment: Sorry.   I thought "following text" referred to the title.

Comment: Because of the package ctexart , the title is being centered. In China, the beginners always use the package ctexart like me。